# Azure function trigger runs once on startup

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using a custom azure function handler (using  with two routes for a POST trigger from cosmosdb(on insertion) and a timer.

They only execute once when I start up my function locally. Is this expected behavior? I expected the function to run each time on DB inserts.

Comment: Can you share the Function definition?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using a custom azure function handler (using with two routes for a POST trigger from cosmosdb (on insertion) and a timer.

As per the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings?tabs=csharp),

*Triggers are the main reason to execute the function, it will define and call a function for that trigger.*

*They have an exactly one trigger in a function.*

> They only execute once when I start up my function locally. Is this expected behavior?

No, this is not an expected behavior. We can create function and it triggered when the data got inserted into cosmosdb.

> I expected the function to run each time on DB inserts.

We tried to reproduced the same scenario and we achieved it.
You can use the following sample code *`triggered azure function when data inserted into cosmosdb`*.

**Example code** :- Azure Cosmos triggered function.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Cosmosdbtriggered
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "cosmosContainer",
            collectionName: "name",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "cosmosconnectionstring",
            LeaseCollectionName = "leases", CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists =true)]IReadOnlyList<Document> input,
            ILogger log)
        {
            if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
            {
                log.LogInformation("Documents modified " + input.Count);
                log.LogInformation("First document Id " + input[0].Id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

local.setting.json
[image]

Data Inserted into cosmos DB.
[image]

After data inserted then azure function executed like below result,

**Output:-**

[image]